# Path-requirements for QProcess::startDetached

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm starting an external tool using QProcess::startDetached and it doesn't start. The log tells:

```
... LOG:...Starting...: C:/Program Files (x86)/AESKU.SYSTEMS/HELIOS/mytool.exe --minimize
... WARNING...failed...: C:/Program Files (x86)/AESKU.SYSTEMS/HELIOS/mytool.exe --minimize
```

Starting the tool in terminal using

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AESKU.SYSTEMS\HELIOS\mytool.exe" --minimize
```

works.

So doesn't it start because of spaces in "Program Files (x86)" or because of wrong slashes?

In C++ I use the call:

```
if(!QProcess::startDetached( wlc_cmdLine ))
    ...
```

Comment: Because of spaces. Also, you should pass arguments in a separate variable.

Comment: Right! That was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

OK, No I've found out.
Both versions of startDetached work:

```
QProcess::startDetached( some_command_line_string_with_args_but_without_spaces );

QProcess::startDetached( some_command_line_string_without_args_but_with_spaces , QStringList()<<"--myarg" );
```

In both versions, even on windows the slashes instead of native back-slashes work fine.